# Pre commit svn hook script to check previous identical log messages?

Tags: svn

I want to create a pre-commit hook script for svn that checks that the commit message isn't identical to one of the last 10 commit messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN Pre-Commit Hook For Identical Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162439/svn-pre-commit-hook-for-identical-messages)

Comment: Code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19234497/960558 require only one change - latest 20 to latest 10 log-messages

Comment: Can you explain ***why*** you want to do this? For example: `BUG1232 - In progress` is a good legitimate commit message. It explains what I was working on and that I'm still working on it. I may have two to four more commit messages that say this exact thing before changing it to `BUG1232 - Completed`.

Comment: @DavidW. - this is bad, stupid and mostly useless (for history) commit-message

Comment: @LazyBadger Why is it bad? It precisely defines what I was working on. If the next release needs this particular change, I can easily locate the revisions I need to include. If there's a problem, and it needs to be pulled out, I can find all of the revision changes. If this bug also appears on another branch, I can find all of the relevant revisions to merge. It's short and precise. What I don't want are comments such as _I modified the foo method_ or _Added a new counter_. These I can see in the code. What I want to know in a commit message not what was changed, but why.

Answer (score 1):

If an earlier commit message is a good match for your changes, then the tool should not get in your way.

I'm extremely picky about the writing style of commit messages, yet, roughly once a week on average, I find myself reusing a previous commit message, and I see nothing wrong with that.

If you are not happy with the commit messages of your teammates then tell them. I do that all the time. This is more likely a social issue, adding more rules will not really help you. Programmers will waste cycles trying to come up with modifications that bypass your rules, to no benefit whatsoever.

I know, this is not an answer to your *question*. But hopefully it is to your *problem*.